# Multiplication of a distribution by locally integrable function

Tags: distribution-theory

If $f=e^{-|x|}$ then how is it true that $f\delta'[\varphi]=-f'\delta[\varphi]-f\delta[\varphi']$ for $\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(\Omega)$? 
We know that for $f\in C^{\infty}$ above estimate true but $f$ given here are not smooth. Suppose we only know that $f\in L_{loc}^1$ or $f$ is Lipschitz continuous. Then is there any way to hold the above equality?
Let if we define in the way that $f\delta_{x_0}[\varphi]=f(x_0)\varphi(x_0)$ and others terms in the same ways.
Then if we mollify $f$ then for $f_{\epsilon}\in C^{\infty}$ above result holds but the problem is that $f_{\epsilon}\to f$ pointwise a.e not for all $x_0$ as $f\in L_{loc}^1$.

Comment: In general, $fu$ for $u$ being a distribution is only defined if $f \in C^\infty.$ What makes you think that $f\delta$ is defined?

Comment: No I am also thinking that it is not possible to define. But I find a result where that estimate was used but f is not smooth. f is only locally integrable or Lipschitz.

Comment: Perhaps the following assignment is possible: $$f'\delta = -e^{-|x|}\operatorname{sgn}(x)\cdot \delta = -\frac{1}{4}e^{-|x|}(\operatorname{sgn}^2(x))' \to 0 $$ since Lipschitz functions can only have at worst a jump discontinuity in their derivatives, which would result in deltas being absorbed via chain rule.

Comment: I think they are possible only weak sense

Comment: There's nothing wrong with working in that regime if that is required of us (a lot of work in this field is determining in which space can our problem make sense), but I would check if there is nothing pathologically wrong with this idea first.

Comment: The formula is obviously based on integration of $f\delta'\varphi = (f\delta\varphi)' - f'\delta\varphi - f\delta\varphi'$. The first term of the right hand side will then vanish. But I don't know how to interpret $f'\delta,$ especially as $f'(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: yes the things are not defined in distribution if $f$ is not smooth. Although $f$ is differentiable a.e.